# BibLaTeX works on Overleaf but not on my Computer

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am trying to get a simple example with a bibliography to run, but on my computer it just shows the reference name in brackets. When I compile the file on overleaf, it works just fine.
Here is my texfile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\bibliography{refs} 
\begin{document} 
Hello\cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

And my bibfile (named refs.bib):

```
@BOOK
{KandR,
AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
YEAR = 1988
 }
```

I use MikTeX and the biblatex package is downloaded. Is there any other installation missing? Do I need the biberfile somewhere?

Comment: Biblatex requires the bib data to be processed via the biber programme. On sharelatex this processing might happen automatically, on your own pc you probably need to tell your editor to run biber. You never mention which editor you use, so we cannot help more.

Comment: I use TeXworks.

Comment: I added biber as processing tool and it worked one time. I then deleted all the other files that are produced when texworks compiles. Now it says the .bcf file is missing. How does it produce that again?

Comment: running pdfLaTeX then biber then pdfLaTeX works. But can I set it to do that automatically?

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). You don't have to run Biber every time you change your document, it is enough to run it whenever you change something about citations and your bibliography. If you want a more automatic solution, check `latexmk` and `arara`.

Comment: I think `latexmk` is what is used behind the scenes in overleaf.

Comment: The `.bcf` is generated by `pdflatex`. Don't delete generated files unless you are, say, ready to archive a project or something and don't want to compile it again any time soon. You can recreate them, of course, but that gets to be a pain.